# Electric current definition

Tags: electric-current

I am studying the concept of electric current and I have a doubt about the definition of the current itself that is the following: "the electric current is a net flow of charge through a chosen sourface".
The book tries to make some examples to let the students understand the concept.
The book, indeed, states that if no electric field is applied to a conductor, the net flux of charge is zero. I am not sure I have understood why. The book also states there are two flows of electrons in both directions so the net flux is zero. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: "The book also states there are two flux of electrons in both directions so the net flux is zero." Not sure what that means, out of context. Maybe you should get another book.

Comment: It states there are two flows of electrons in a conductor in which it is not applied an electric field. One flux is in a verse, and the other is in the opposite verse.

Comment: The net charge through an oriented surface is only zero if the same amount of charge moves in as out

Answer (score 1):

Electrons in a metal (at one level of modelling) move about randomly, much like molecules in a gas.

So if you consider a cross-sectional surface through a wire, at any moment there will be many electrons moving through that surface from left to right. But at the same time there will be a very nearly equal number of electrons moving through the surface from right to left.

So the net movement of electrons from one side of the surface to the other is very nearly zero (and if we average over time, it gets closer to zero the longer we average), and we say the current through that surface is zero.

If we apply an electric field, say, from left to right, then the number of electrons moving right to left will be ever so slightly higher than the number moving left to right, and we'll have a non-zero current from left to right.

Comment: That's right but I want to know how I can demostrate that the net current is zero in a counductor in which it is not applied an electric field. Can I suppose there are two currents of electrons I have to sum to obtain the net current?

Comment: You could figure out the flux of electrons from left to right, and the flux from right to left, and then show they're equal. But I'd just say that by symmetry they must be equal and be done.

Comment: Ok, that was my problem. I was in trouble because I knew the positive verse of the current is that of the positive charges and the negative current (in the opposite verse) is that of the electrons. But in this case, both the flows of current are negative so the convention does not apply.

Comment: @angelo the positive carriers (protons) are localized and confined in the atomic nuclei, so they don't move around and don't contribute to current.

Comment: I was talking about the Benjamin Franklin's convention.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea what you mean by the positive or negative "verse" of current.

Comment: Let us say you have a current of 5 A from right to left. You can immagine this current as the flux of protons from right to left (of course only the electrons move through a conductor). A current of 5 A has the same effect of a current of electrons from left to right.

Comment: But what does the word "verse" mean here? Are they singing a song?

Comment: It means the way the current is following (e.g. from right to left).

Comment: OK, I guess you're translating from Italian or something, but "verse" doesn't mean that in English. It is a part of a song.

Comment: Yes I am from Italy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105460/discussion-between-angelo-giannuzzi-and-the-photon).